# Error when installing pip requirements.txt with Ansible, but not when doing it manually on the server

Tags: ansible

When I try the following from my playbook I get an error

```
- name: Install project requirements
  remote_user: john
  pip:
    name=django-authtools
    virtualenv="/home/john/ve"
```

However, if if I go on to the server and source the env and then run `pip install django-authtools` it works a treat.

Other packages works, it's only this one that fails. I've checked that the other packages get installed in the virtualenv from Ansible so it's not a case of it trying to install it elsewhere.

The error:

```
  File "/home/john/ve/build/django-authtools/setup.py", line 26, in <module>

    long_description='\n\n'.join([read('README.rst'), read('CHANGES.rst')]),

  File "/home/john/ve/build/django-authtools/setup.py", line 12, in read

    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

  File "/home/john/ve/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 550: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm using Python 3 in my ve.

**UPDATE**
I've also tried with:

```
- name: Install project requirements
  remote_user: john
  pip:
    name=django-authtools
    virtualenv="/home/john/ve"
    executable="pip3.4"
```

**UPDATE #2**

I've tried `/home/john/ve/bin/pip install -r /home/john/project/requirements.txt` as that works on the server but through Ansible it still fails.
This boggles the mind

Answer (score 2):

Eventually found the issue: locale

Ansible sets the locale to C and in my case `django-authtools` failed.

A quick way around this:

Create the following vars:

```
host_locale: en_GB.UTF-8

host_locale_dict: {
  LANG: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_COLLATE: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_CTYPE: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_MESSAGES: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_MONETARY: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_NUMERIC: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_TIME: "{{ host_locale }}",
  LC_ALL: "{{ host_locale }}",
}
```

and in your task set the `environment`:

```
environment: host_locale_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting this in the ansible.cfg file under the `[defaults]` section.

```
module_lang    = en_US.UTF-8
```

Another thing to note is that I had less issues with a directory structure like:

```
DistributedReporting/
└── venv
    └── src
```

As opposed to:

```
DistributedReporting/
├── src
└── venv
```